Custom title in a wordpress page edit mode with ACF fields
A couple of images will be easier to describe what I need to do:
Here I am entering a new product's title and description, which is simply a repeater with 2 texts.

When I validate, I get my entry with the name "product information", as it is the name of the ACF layout. But I would like instead for the title to become "product information : super shoes". That would help the editor to more easily locate the different entries.

Can this be achieved?

we would definitely need to see the code you're using to display the fields.

The displayed fields are within the Wordpress dashboard, so there is no code. Fields are all set in the ACF plugin.

ACF has a built in filter for their flexible rows which you may be able to leverage/adjust for your own use on your repeater, or investigate and build your own:
apply_filters( 'acf/fields/flexible_content/layout_title', $title, $field, $layout, $i );

Their documentation covers this here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-flexible_content-layout_title/
